# List content of node in another view

Tags: views, nodes

I have a view of some custom content type and want to link the name of each object in the view to another view containing its details. At the moment, I have the "link this field to its node" box checked but it doesn't display it in some sort of table, just a list like *Title: value*.

Could you please tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the node link to anything you would like with "Rewrite the output of this field", it should link to something like /yourviewpath/$nid, where $nid is the node id and the argument for the view that contains the node details.

Comment: So what you're saying is I should create a view with the details for each specific object, right?

Comment: You need an additional view which takes the node id as argument, yes.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how I could make it just show the stuff just for a certain object? Currently I've only set the node id as argument but it gives the table with every object in it.

Comment: Introduction to Views arguments: http://drupal.org/node/611152
Set the node id as argument, test it by setting "Provide default argument" to a fixed entry (some node id)

Comment: You're brilliant. Thanks :) Now could you just tell me how to make the view show the fields as rows, not columns?

Comment: By the way, I did that and when I enter a random $nid, it works, but then for the path, how can I make it automatically pull the object's $nid? So I want to link the name of the object to /mypath/$nid_valueForThatObject. Do you know how I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: - Add a page display and set the path to mypath/%
- For fields as rows, use "Style" and "Row style" to set the appearance

Comment: @Eelke let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/932/discussion-between-sorin-cioban-and-eelke)

Comment: I added the page display to the Details view. Its path is details/%. But in the main view where I have the object names and I try to link them to their own list of details, if I type the path details/% for the link, it will not show anything as it's probably not getting the $nid. Can you please email me - sorinc03@me.com